# Angularjs http.get in ng-repeat causes "10 $digest iterations reached. Aborting" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to load an image after every nth index in an ng-repeat block using $http.get, but I keep getting the 10 $digest iterations reached error.

Here is the code that's causing the problem:

```
<ul ng-repeat-start='product in products track by product.id'> 
    <li class="product-desc"> {{ product.desc }} </li>
</ul>
<div ng-if='($index + 1) % 20 === 0' ng-repeat-end> 
<img ng-src='{{getThumbnail($index + 1)}}'/> 
</div>
```

```
$scope.getThumbnail = function getThumbnail(index) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/display/?r=' + index).then(function (data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }) 
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Function expression with $http is interpolation is never a good idea. Remember interpolation are evaluated multiple times (every time when digest occurs).

Comment: What is value of data?

Comment: @Chandermani, data would be binary data for the image itself. Is there a better way to load this image? Maybe just plug the url directly into ng-src? But, I want the image to load asynchronously so that might not be the best way to handle it.

Comment: Well if you have url, please use it. Image will automatically load async. Why do you think it will not

Comment: @Chandermani, actually you are right, there is no reason to think that ng-src is synchronous. I am able to solve the problem like that, however I still wanted to figure out why I was getting that error when trying to load the image via $http.get. 
Thanks!

Comment: What is returned from the function should be fixed (compared with angular.equal method), else Angular detects a change and re runs a digest cycle. To safeguard against infinite cycles Angular breaks the process at 10 cycles.